# How to link the popup JavaScript and popup aspx page while implementing Ribbon toolbar button in Tridion?

Tags: javascript, tridion

I am implementing a ribbon tool bar button for component view.

When I click in the RTF field the button will be enabled. When I click on the button it will open a aspx page. When the aspx page is opened the corresponding JavaScript should initialize by default. But in my case it is not happening.
I have given common names to the JavaScript and aspx page. Please suggest how to debug this problem and get a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you saying that your JavaScript file doesn't get included at all?

Or that the "initialize" method isn't getting called?

If it's the former, you should look at your dependencies. Normally you would have a group in your Editor configuration file which includes the .js file and optionally a .css file as well. You would then include a dependency on this group in your .aspx.cs file, by including a ControlResources attribute (passing in the name of the group).

If the problem is that your "initialize" method isn't being called, you should check if you are registering the view (e.g. calling `$display.registerView(FullNameOfYourClassIncludingNamespce)` at the bottom of your JavaScript file)

Comment: Peter Thanks for your response. Now the popup javascript is getting loaded but when I am opening the component is not opening and it is throwing the error like 
"Message: 'events' is null or not an object".

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are saying, but if you get that error in the Component editing screen there is likely a server-side error preventing the JavaScript files from loading correctly. Check with your developer tools / Fiddler / Firebug to look for errors - and check for warnings from ASP.NET in the Application Event Log.

Comment: I had a similar error bugging me for a while, and it was because my JS had Type.RegisterNamespace (instead of Type.registerNamespace) (notice the lower case r) and another one I can't remember with the same issue. After changing that it started working.

Comment: Nuno Thanks for your response. Peter I added resource group name which is created in configuration file and the same is given in aspx page ControlResource attribute. After clicking the ribbon button, popup page is getting opened but the popup aspx page is not getting linked with popup js file. So it is not returning value to the component creation page instead refreshing the popup page. Anyone please help in this issue. Thanks in advance. Early response is appreciated.

Comment: Peter I am able to debug the button java script file using firebug tool. But how can I check the popup page java script file? I can't see that javascript in the script section of firebug addon. Please suggest me a way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PeterKjaer Thank you very much.I am able to solve my problem. Unfortunately I given wrong class name to the $display.registerView() method. I corrected it and it is working cool now. Even I am able to add the Image to the button.